# Using $("#select-id").prop("selectedIndex") In A Select Statement

Tags: jquery

OK, so I've been made to understand that using this

```
$("#select-id").prop("selectedIndex")
```

in conjunction with this

```
$("#select-id").prop("selectedIndex", 1)
```

Would help obtain the results I'm looking for in getting certain elements passed back to a select statement, but I cannot find any examples of usage for this.

Lets say I have 6 elements in the select, and I have them being compared against something in another field. What would be the recommended way to set this up? I understand use a for loop, and then an if statement to iterate through the values, but I don't quite get how to use the aforementioned .prop statements.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
function compareAmts($FIELDSwitchText, $FIELDSwitchPull)
{
var SwitchAdv = 0;
temp = $("#FIELD_SwitchPull").val();
var SwitchComm = parseInt(temp.replace(/\,/g,''));

if($("#FIELD_SwitchText").val()!=""){
    SwitchAdv = parseInt($("#FIELD_SwitchText").val());
```

Basically this collects the information, I then need to use the 2 lines above in a For Loop to Get and Set the SelectedIndex, and thus the Select DropDown

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you looking to simply set the `<select>` element's value? IE change the selection?

Comment: `$("#select-id").val()` will return an array of selected values or just the selected value.

Comment: Yes, based on a value in a text box. So If text box < select box (based on an index) then select box must decrement to value in close range to what was in the text box.

Comment: You haven't really explained your problem, you should provide a proper example.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to provide an example.  I've written something that collects the values of the 2 fields, they need to be compared, and possibly changed.

Comment: function compareAmts($FIELDSwitchText, $FIELDSwitchPull)
{
 var SwitchAdv = 0;
 temp = $("#FIELD_SwitchPull").val();
    var SwitchComm = parseInt(temp.replace(/\,/g,''));
 
 if($("#FIELD_SwitchText").val()!=""){
  SwitchAdv = parseInt($("#FIELD_SwitchText").val());
Basically this collects the information, I then need to use the 2 lines above in a For Loop to Get and Set the SelectedIndex, and thus the Select DropDown.

Comment: just provide the html code of the SELECT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to select a specific option in the select by its value, use `val()`. For example:

```
$('#select-id').val('foo');
```

Would select the following option:

```
<select id="select-id">
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="foo">Foo</option> <!-- jQuery code selects this one -->
    <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>
```

*Update*

If you have a specific item index you want to select, you can use `eq()` to get the specific option. Given the above HTML, the following would also select the `foo` option:

```
$('#select-id option').eq(1).prop('selected', true);
```

Comment: I'm trying to take a text value, and compare it against the multiple values in the select statement, Whichever one it's closest to (on the lower end of the spectrum (ie if the number is 2300 in the text box, the select would decrement to 2000)

Comment: So that would mean SelectedIndex, 5 for example.

Comment: But I can't figure out how to do it using the aforementioned Select-ID, .PROP lines, and that's how I've been instructed to do it, and it definitely makes sense to do it that way.

Comment: The way things are setup, I can't simply go by options like that I have to get and set the index.

Comment: Ok, I've just added an update to my answer - is that any closer to what you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
var $select = $("#select-id");
var value = $('textarea').val(); // Or whatever

$select.find('option').each(function (index) {
    if ( $(this).text() == value ) { // Or whatever other criteria you have...
        $select.prop('selectedIndex', index);
        return false;
    }
});
```