# how to set the value of a dropdown programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

how do I trigger the change event for a given dropdown? $("#programname").change() (if using jquery of course..)

```
<label for="selectprogramfilter">Program: </label>
<select id="programname" name="selectprogramfilter" class="selectservicefilter" onchange="dropdownClick()">
${DataList}
  </select>
</div>
```

where ${DataList} is

```
    <option value="null">All</option>
    <option value="COMPREHENSIVE HEALTH PLANS">MHP</option>
<option value="MI HEALTH LINK">ICO</option>
<option value="HK-DENTAL">HK-Dental</option>
<option value="Healthy Michigan Plan">HMP</option>
```

I just need to reset the **null** value and **All** text in the dropdown in a jquery function but unable to achieve it.

```
function overallClick(){
    $('#programname').prop('selectedIndex',1);  
    $('#programname').val('1').change();
    $('#programname option:selected').text('null'); 
}
```

Comment: why did you call `dropdownClick()` on change but you have a function named as `overallClick`? why do you trigger the `change` event from inside the handler (supposedly change event handler but can't say for sure) causing infinite recursion? what do you mean by saying _"I just need to reset the null value and All text in the dropdown in a jquery function but unable to achieve it."_?

Comment: There ia a different button which works with overallClick

Comment: I mean to say that on the button click which calls function overallClick will result in choosing 1st option value that is 'All'

Comment: then your question is: how to set the value of a dropdown programmatically? `$("#programname").val('null');` and how do I trigger the change event for a given dropdown? `$("#programname").change()` (if using jquery of course.. in vanilla js it's different)

Comment: yes  this is the same

Comment: yes it's the same as `$('#programname').val('1').change();` but you are attempting to change the value as `1` and there's no option with value `1`. So maybe suddendly your question becomes: how to set the the first option(!) of a dropdown as selected?

Comment: what it should be... i put 1 as index

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251921/discussion-between-dhs-and-diego-d).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591535/using-select-id-propselectedindex-in-a-select-statement it's a duplicate

Comment: I also know this but lol nothing comes from putting 1  :)

Comment: What is the point of this supposed to be in the first place? You are trying to trigger this with an onchange handler - so, every time the user _makes_ a selection, you want to reset it? Then what for are you even _letting_ them make any choice to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe there is button which reset it...

Comment: `.val("1")` selects the `<option>` with `value="1"`.  There's isn't one, so this isn't what you're *trying* to do.  It's unclear what you're *trying* to do.  Your `value='null'` is the *text* `"null"` not `null`.  Are you trying to select the first `<option>`?   I suggest removing the `value=null` and using `.val("")`.   To *trigger* the change, add `.change()` (as you have, but does nothing as you've not changed it using `.val("1")`

Comment: _"there is button which reset it..."_ - not in the code you have shown us above. Why are you showing us something _different_ than the actual problem?

Comment: Equally, `$(option).text('null')` will set the option's *text* to `"null"` - why would you want to do this.

Comment: Please update your question to explain exactly what you're trying to do.   It seems you're almost there (`.val("")`) but there's some confusion as to what the end goal is (if it's not just resetting back to "all") https://jsfiddle.net/omns7vwf/

Comment: To answer your question *how do I trigger the change event* - you call `.change()` (as detailed in [numerous existing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjquery%5D+trigger+select+change+event))    So your actual question should be: *why is change() not triggering change event* and the answer is because you're trying to select something that doesn't exist.

Comment: null i want to give to db and All i want to show in dropdown

Comment: *Just* `$('#programname').val('null').change();` - remove the other lines

Answer (score 0):

-Try set the selected index to zero which selects the first  element.

```
function overallClick() {
  $('#programname').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
}
```

Comment: $('#programname').prop('selectedIndex', 0); 
 $('#programname').val('1').change();
 $('#programname option:selected').text('null');  like this

Comment: To choose the 1st option value, just adding below line inside onclick function will work.
$('#programname').prop('selectedIndex', 0);